# Complicated condition on data Frame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data frame

`X      y         z       count
1      1          1        2
1      1          2        1 
1      3          1        4
2      2          2        100
2      7          5        1
3      3          7        6
4      7          3        9`

x,y, and z are coordinates and they are all together unique.

I want to retrieve the points that either have their `count` >= `threshold` or their neighbors which have `count` >= `threshold`.

I used the following Code for it

```
`df=df[(df["count"]>=theta) | (df[df["X"]+1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["X"]+2>=theta]) | 
                              (df[df["X"]+3>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["X"]-1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["X"]-2>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["X"]-3>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["y"]+1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["y"]+2>=theta]) | 
                              (df[df["y"]+3>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["y"]-1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["y"]-2>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["y"]-3>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["z"]+1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["z"]+2>=theta]) | 
                              (df[df["z"]+3>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["z"]-1>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["z"]-2>=theta]) |
                              (df[df["z"]-3>=theta])]
`
```

But this code doesn't work. My problem is to form a condition on the other rows while I'm on the current row and also on how to perform a condition on the next and previous point in `x` or `y` or `z` coordinates.I want to check the third neighbors.
`shift' could maybe do the job, but I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, First choose all rows with count >= theta with

```
df1 = df[df["count"] >= theta]
```

Next iterate through the rows of df1 and check if close points have count < theta
in df. This would look something like this.

```
temp = [df1]
for ind,row in df1.iterrows():
    temp.append(df[(df["X"] == row["X"]+1) & (df["count"] < theta)])
df_final = pd.concat(temp)
```

Here you could add more conditions as necessary, see that I am looking for count < theta as the greater ones would already be in the df1 dataframe. The final line combines all the dataframes in the list into one.

This makes accessing another row unnecessary.

- Note that I have not tested the code so the syntax might need tweaking but the idea is what I wanted to convey.

Comment: after the little change ` df1 = df[df["c"] >= theta]

temp=[]

for ind,row in df1.iterrows():
    temp.append(df[(df["x"] == row["x"]+1) & (df["c"] < theta)])

temp = pd.concat(temp)
df_final=pd.concat([df1,temp])
print(df_final)`    its work. Thanks @Srinivas V